# Im trying to automate curl put/delete/get to an application of an xml using python(pycurl)

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I have a curl statement :
    curl -v -X PUT --header "Expect: " --header "X-XCAP-Asserted-Identity: \"sip:14257701100@msg.lab.t-mobile.com\"" --header "Content-Type: application/auth-policy+xml" --header "User-Agent: Web-Serv-Gateway-v1" --header "Content-Encoding: gzip" -T 14257701100_AccessRule_gzip.xml.gz http://10.3.11.142:8060/cdb/xcap/org.openmobilealliance.access-rules/users/sip:1100@mavenir.lab/access-rules

Im trying to use python to automate the request. But PUT request fails using below code as the data(xml) is not sent.but I read the data and pass on like below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import commands
import string
import subprocess
import urllib2
import pycurl
import StringIO

xml1=open('14257701100_GroupInfo.xml','r+')
xmldata=xml1.read()
print(xmldata)
response = StringIO.StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://10.3.11.142:8060/cdb/xcap/org.openmobilealliance.groups/users/sip:14257701100@msg.lab.t-mobile.com/list-service')
#c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://110.3.11.142:8060/cdb/xcap/org.openmobilealliance.groups/users/sip:14257701100@msg.lab.t-mobile.com/list-service')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, response.write)
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, ['X-XCAP-Asserted-Identity: \"sip:14257701100@msg.lab.t-mobile.com\"','Content-Type: application/vnd.oma.poc.groups+xml','User-Agent: Web-Serv-Gateway-v1'])
c.setopt(c.CUSTOMREQUEST,"PUT")
c.setopt(c.PUT,True)
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS,xmldata)
try:
    c.perform()
except pycurl.error, e:
    raise e
http_code = c.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
print('HTTP CODE IS: %d',http_code)
c.close()
print('done')

####
```

In application logs the xml data is empty.

Thanks
Shrinidhi

Comment: Have you looked into the [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)? It's much more succinct and Pythonic (and also vastly more easy to use).

Comment: Have you tried using the requests python library? Then the request looks simpler

    "response = requests.put(URL, data=data, headers=headers)"

Comment: Thanks kungphu and jase , my python version is 2.6.6 and the requests module is not available in this machine by default, is there a way to use it in pycurl, Or requests library is the only best way to do it.

Comment: Install using pip. "pip install requests" or easy_install. I'm not 100% sure but it might be backwards compatible as well

Comment: Have installed requests module....will try and explore more and see if i can achieve all the operations like PUT/Delete/Get and update...Thanks....